# Need to remove string from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, numbers, underscore.js

I have an array inside a for loop like this:

`var arr = ["abc", "5", "city", "2", "area", "2", "max", "choice"];`

And I need only number like this:

`var arr = ["5","2","2"];`

So can someone please help here.

Comment: Those `"5"`, `"2"`, and `"2"` are still strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach by using a converted number to a string and compare with the original value.

```js
var array = ["abc", "5", "city", "2", "area", "2", "max", "choice"],
    result = array.filter(v => (+v).toString() === v);

console.log(result);
```

Just shorter approach with [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite)

```js
var array = ["abc", "5", "city", "2", "area", "2", "max", "choice"],
    result = array.filter(isFinite);

console.log(result);
```

While tagged with [underscore.js](/questions/tagged/underscore.js), you could use the filtering and callback from underscore.

```js
var array = ["abc", "5", "city", "2", "area", "2", "max", "choice"],
    result = _.filter(array, _.isFinite);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If there are any trailing zeros in decimal like `"2.10"` this won't work

Comment: isFinite() is a great way to do this

Comment: I wasn't aware of isFinite coercing before determining numbers. Very useful! +1

Answer (score 1):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the strings that are integers when they're coerced to one:

```js
var arr = ["abc", "5", "city", "2", "", "area", "2", "max", "choice"];

const out = arr.filter(el => (
  el !== '' && Number.isInteger(Number(el)))
);

console.log(out)
```

Comment: `Number.isInteger(+"")` returns true too.

Comment: Nice catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ["abc", "5", "city", "2", "area", "2", "max", "choice"];

const filtered = arr.filter(item => !isNaN(item));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Why the downvote though, that's a totally valid answer. Have the decency to explain your actions when you do them ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method with `isNaN` function `var numbers = arr.filter(c=> !isNaN(c));`

```js
var arr = ["abc", "5", "city", "2", "area", "2", "max", "choice"];
var numbers = arr.filter(c=> !isNaN(c));
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `forEach` loops and checking using `isNaN()`

```js
var arr = ["abc", "5", "city", "2", "area", "2", "max"];
var a=[];
arr.forEach(e=>isNaN(e)?true:a.push(e))
console.log(a)
```

Comment: `isNaN(Number(e))` - converting using `Number` is redundant. `isNaN` is already enough. It's badly named - it's actually `isArgumentGoingToConvertToNaNWhenYouConvertItToNumber`